# Why copy constructor is getting called?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following piece of code and there are a couple of things that bother me the most:

1. **At what point in time does original constructor call happen?**
2. **Under which circumstances, the copy constructor is getting called?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Samp {
    char str[10] = "Default";
public:
    Samp(char s[]) { strcpy(str, s); printf("Constructor\n"); }
    Samp(const Samp& s) { printf("Copy Constructor\n"); }
    ~Samp() { printf("Destructor\n"); }

    char* out() {
        return str;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Samp& s) {
        stream << s.str;

        return stream;
    }
};

void output(Samp s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::function<void(Samp s)> o;
    o = output;

    o((char*)"Hello");

    return 0;
}
```

On execution, the program provides the following output

```
Constructor
Copy Constructor
Default
Destructor
Destructor
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you debug step by step and see which statement gave which output?

Comment: I guess you are having difficulty in getting this due to all output getting generated by `o((char*)"Hello")`. So I would suggest you put breakpoints where ever you are using printf. And then debug step by step

Comment: Thank you @Nitesh, I've already have done some investigation and it turned out that indeed original constructor gets invoked on line 38 after that stack frame gets destroyed, then execution returns back to 38 line, thereafter "o" function gets called, but the object construction happens due to call for copy constructor, that is what I'm trying to get, what is the mechanism causes this to happen

Comment: The original constructor call is happening to convert `(char *)"Hello"` to a `Samp`.  The copy constructor is then being called as that first constructed object is copied in being passed by value to `output`.    Note that the copy constructor does not change the `str` member, so printing it produces `Default`.  Then the two objects are destroyed, before control reaches the `return 0` in `main()`.   Depending on age of your compiler, elision of temporaries *may* happen - but, from the output you describe, no elision is occurring.

Comment: Great! Thank you @Peter, now I get it. Initially, I supposed that there would be no difference between output((char*)"Hello");  and o((char*)"Hello");, since the direct call of the "output" doesn't cause the temporary object to be created.

Comment: since it's c++, use std::string instead of char[10]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments to a `std::function` invocation are passed by [*perfect forwarding*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) through to the callable object stored inside the `std::function` object.

So the behaviour of `o(args...)` is not the same as `output(args...)`. Instead it is the same as:

```
output( std::forward<Args...>(args...) );
```

or in this concrete example,

```
output( std::forward<Samp>( (char *)"Hello" ) );
```

In this example we see that "perfect" forwarding is not so perfect, as this code has slightly different behaviour to `output( (char *)"Hello" );` .

The signature of the chosen overload for `forward` is `Samp&& forward(Samp&& arg);`. So there must be a temporary materialized for the `arg` to bind to for the function call to`std::forward`; that is the "Constructor" that you see.

Then the "Copy constructor" is initialization of the `output` function's parameter from the return value of `std::forward`. That could be a move operation, if `Samp` had a move-constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor and Copy of you class called in one place basicly.
When you  use youre function its create Samp S by construct and then copy it to void fnc.

Answer (score 2):

```
void output(Samp s)
```

This is the problem. This function pass object by value. When you call

```
o((char*)"Hello")
```

, it creates an temporary Samp object by default constructor, and create another new object by copy constructor to pass to the function.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed a signature for the "output" function to the following: void output(const Samp& s); and it works. Could you possibly provide an explanation, why this temporary object gets created in the first place?

Comment: Just because output function need an Samp object, not a char*, so it create a temporary object by Samp(char[])

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer, as `output((char*)"Hello");` does not create any temporary. The function parameter is initialized by the `char *` with no intermediate objects involved. The answer should explain the difference between `output((char*)"Hello");` and `o((char*)"Hello");`.

Comment: Also the Samp class does not even have a default constructor, so your statement "it creates an temporary Samp object by default constructor" cannot be correct

Comment: I agree with @M.M. The function signature, ideally, would create a Samp-object through the constructor taking a char[]. No copy involved. The problem has to do with std::function.